# Invalid directory. The bundle Payload/Runner.app/PlugIns/Pods_Runner.framework It should be under Frameworks

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

We developed a Flutter app and we want to publish the update on App Store.

But we got this error (screenshot)[image]

You find below the setup

```
MacOS Sonoma 14.0

flutter doctor

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.6, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-x64, locale en-CI)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.82.3)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] Network resources
```